# What's the difference between place-holding and space-filling?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, idioms

I encountered the counter-position of the two in one of the SE answers. I wonder what's the difference.

Comment: Context please? Or a link to the answers you mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: You probably have in mind [this SE answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/81827/51090): "Such pages may serve purposes ranging from **place-holding to space-filling** and content separation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *placeholder* is a dummy object that is intended to be replaced at some point by something real.

A *space-filler* is an object that is not intended to be removed or replaced.  Its only role is to occupy the space, and to do so for the duration.  The small styrofoam peanuts or plastic air bags in a shipping box are "space fillers".